# How to make button enabled in AvaloniaUI depending on Textbox value

Tags: user-interface, button, textbox, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm new to Avalonia, so my code should be pretty basic. I have 1 window with 1 panel in it that is:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<Button Content="Say HI" Click="OnButtonClicked" IsEnabled="{Binding Enable}"/>
```

That panel has TextBlock, TextBox, and button. The button is not enabled by default.
My question is, how can I enable it when the value of textBox is changes. Here is my Model class that already has some basic logic in it:

```
class HelloViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string greeting = "";
    private string name = "";
    public bool Enable = false;

    public string Greeting
    {
        get => greeting;

        set
        {
            if (value != greeting)
            {
                greeting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Enable = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if(value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Enable = true;
            }
        }
    }

   

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new MVVM Project from the Avalonia Template you will get a `ViewModelBase` class. I would suggest to use that.

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
{
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Greeting {
        get => "Welcome to Avalonia.";
    }

    private bool enable = false;
    public bool Enable
    {
        get => enable;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref enable, value);
    }

    private string name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref name, value);
            Enable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Just to make sure, the MainWindow.xaml

```
  <Design.DataContext>
      <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
  </Design.DataContext>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" />

  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
  <Button Content="Say HI" Click="OnButtonClicked" IsEnabled="{Binding Enable}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Where `vm` is `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:<YourNamespaceContainingTheViewModel>;assembly=<YourProject>"`

Additional infos and how to set the ViewModel from CodeBehind can be found [here](https://avaloniaui.net/docs/binding/datacontext).

### Edit

If you only want to enable the button, when a specific text is set, you can add a condition like that:

```
public string Name
{
  get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref name, value);
        if (Name == Greeting)
        {
            Enable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Enable = false;
        }
    }
}
```